# Can I apply the constraint while constructing the Lagrangian?

Tags: optimization, matrices

Consider the problem:

$\min_X ||XAX^T||_F$

s.t. $X^TX=I$

If A and X are real matrices, the lagrangian will be $tr(XAX^TXA^TX^T)+\sum_i\alpha_i(x_i^Tx_i-1)+\sum_i\sum_{j\neq i}\beta_{ij} q_i^Tq_j$ where $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_{ij}$ are Lagrangian multipliers.

Can I apply $X^TX=I$ here such that the Lagrangian becomes $tr(XAA^TX^T)+\sum_i\alpha_i(x_i^Tx_i-1)+\sum_i\sum_{j\neq i}\beta_{ij} q_i^Tq_j$?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on math.SE